# Find area under $y= x^2 - x^4$ from x=-1 to x=0 using the Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration, area, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I'm trying to find the area under $y= x^2 - x^4$ from $x=-1$ to $x=0$ using the Riemann sum.

This is what I've done so far:

$\Delta x = 1/n$

$x_i =-1 + i/n$

$A = R_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} {\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta x ((x_i)^2 - (x_i)^4) }$

$A = \lim_{n\to \infty} \Delta x{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1 + i/n)^2 - (-1 + i/n)^4 }$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I tried expanding the terms $(x_i)^2$ and $(x_i)^4$ but that didn't seem to help.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. 
 Do you know how to sum consecutive squares? 
 [Here](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/sums-of-powers-of-positive-integers-pierre-de-fermat-1601-1665-france) is a page I found about the sum of consecutive fourth powers

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1 + i/n)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{i-n}n)^2\\
=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\frac{i}n)^2\\=\frac 1{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (i^2)$$
To go from the first line to the second we took the terms in the reverse order.  Now perform the sum.  The same thing happens for the other part.  When you consider the $\Delta x$ all the terms but the first in each will go away when you let $n \to \infty$

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct since f(1/10) is not the same as f(-1/10). It's the same when f(x) = x^2 but is not necessarily the same for other functions, such as f(x) = x^3. Also, I don't see how the order is reversed. It seems you started i at 0 instead of 1. Shouldn't i go from n to 0 in order to have it in reverse order?

Comment: Are you able to elaborate further to help me understand how to solve this problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: $f$ is gone because you replaced it with its value in terms of $i,n$.  Note that $i-n$ has all the numbers from $1-n$ to $0$.  In my sum, $i$ goes from $0$ to $n-1$.  That is why I changed the limits, so I would have all the same terms up to sign, and the square takes care of the sign.